# Segmentation Fault Accessing Singleton C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, redis, segmentation-fault

## Overview

I am writing a helper class to make calls to Redis easier with the [xRedis](https://github.com/0xsky/xredis) drivers in C++, but I am continually receiving a segmentation fault upon requesting or sending any information to the instance.

I think this has to do with the way I'm storing the xRedis and RedisDBIdx instances, and possibly the way I'm storing the RedisAdmin instance within the main application, but I'm unable to see the right way to set these up after several attempts.

Relevant Code is below, and a few notes on debugging steps I have taken myself.

### Debugging Notes

- Redis Server is started successfully, and log output shows successful connection to server on instance startup
- The call fails whether a set or exists command is sent to the server
- GDB Output shows below, and logs show the same happenning on either exists or set calls:

  ```
  Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
  RedisPool::GetConnection (this=0x0, cahcetype=0, dbindex=0, ioType=0) at src/xRedisPool.cpp:124
  124        || (ioType>SLAVE)
  ```

### Code

#### redis_admin.h

```
#include "xredis/xRedisClient.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <string>

class xRedisAdmin
{
xRedisClient xRed;
public:
    xRedisAdmin(RedisNode conn_list[], int conn_list_size);
    ~xRedisAdmin();
    const char * load ( const char * key );
    bool save ( const char * key, const char * msg );
    bool exists ( const char * key );
    bool del ( const char * key );
};
```

#### redis_admin.cpp

```
xRedisAdmin::xRedisAdmin(RedisNode conn_list[], int conn_list_size)
{
enum {
CACHE_TYPE_1,
CACHE_TYPE_2,
CACHE_TYPE_MAX,
};

xRed.Init(CACHE_TYPE_MAX);
bool bret = xRed.ConnectRedisCache(conn_list, conn_list_size, CACHE_TYPE_1);
//Log results
}

//Exists
bool xRedisAdmin::exists(const char * key)
{
RedisDBIdx d(&xRedis);
char szKey[256] = {0};
sprintf(szKey, key);
return xRed.exists(d, szKey);
}

//Save
bool xRedisAdmin::save(const char * key, const char * val)
{
RedisDBIdx d(&xRed);
char szKey[256] = {0};
sprintf(szKey, key);
bool ret_val = xRed.set(d, szKey, val);
//Log output
return ret_val;
}
```

#### Main.cpp

```
xRedisAdmin *xRed;

void example_callback() {
    bool bRet = xRed->save("key", "c_str");
}

int main()
{
    xRedisAdmin x (RedisList1, conn_list_size);
    xRed = &x;

    example_callback();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it's confusing to say the least, using `xRedis` as both the name of a global pointer to `xRedisAdmin`, and as the name of a class member of type `xRedisClient`

Comment: That's a fair point, and not hard to change, I will test it.  I thought that, as a private variable, end user wouldn't have access to call this and therefor there should be no issue

Comment: You should use `key` rather than `szKey`  (but that shouldn't affect this exact example)

Comment: @AlexBarry You have the [source to this library](https://github.com/0xsky/xredis/blob/master/src/xRedisPool.cpp).  Why not step into the source code?  The error appears at line 124, and you could simply set a breakpoint on that line and see what the function is doing and how you got there by inspecting the call stack.

Comment: You'll probably have to debug your code. Do a backtrace and find out how you ended up in `GetConnection` with `this` being null

Comment: Posting your exact code would help too (`main.cpp` won't compile as posted, who knows what else you left out that might be important)

Comment: Honestly, I thought the problem was my use of the code and not the library itself.  I assumed the problem was in how I was allocating variables and memory, not how the library was.  Do you believe that this assumption was incorrect?

Comment: @AlexBarry -- You have a reference point to start looking.  What you should do is work backwards, starting from the faulting function to find out what values it's using.  Then find out how those (bad) values got there by going back in the call stack until you get to the line in your code that started this chain.

Comment: It's an application I've been working on for several months with a lot more going on (Log4Cpp, Couchbase, ZMQ, etc), which is why I condensed it down.  However, this issue only started occurring in tests after adding Redis Connectivity.  All of the other libraries appear to be functioning correctly in tests.  It is only when the application goes to hit the Redis instance that I see problems. full source code can be found [here](https://github.com/AO-StreetArt/CLyman), on the dev branch

Comment: Did you see the `this=0x0` part? Go up the call stack and see how you managed to dereference a nullptr.

Comment: @AlexBarry  You have all the information necessary (the library source, your source, etc.) to debug this fully.  This is not a "black box" scenario, where you don't have the full source.  The `this` pointer is null, meaning that somewhere in the call chain between your call and the failing call, a null is being used as an object.   Just look at the call stack and see where in the chain the code goes awry.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, this is what I get for violating the Rule of Threes.

I did not have a copy constructor for the Redis Admin, and the xRed object inside it became null on assignment because of this.  Use of new & delete, rather than creating in the main method, did resolve the issue. proved the solution to the issue

Thanks all who commented and gave me answers & support!

Alex